# Azure CosmosDB MongoDB How To Query: Query Explorer

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am exploring Azure CosmosDB and having trouble with understanding how I can query my collection.  I created a web application to add and query the data but I want to search within Azure and do not know how I should structure my query.

Currently I query my collection running to return everything.

```
SELECT * FROM c
```

This returns a lot of information.  Here is a sample of what the data looks like.

```
  {
    "$t": 3,
    "$v": {
      "searchTerm": {
        "$t": 2,
        "$v": "test"
      },
      "searchDate": {
        "$t": 9,
        "$v": 1501606675858
      },
      "_id": {
        "$t": 7,
        "$v": "Y³\u0013&Ò#\bø\u0005+ú"
      },
      "__v": {
        "$t": 16,
        "$v": 0
      }
    },
    "id": "NTk4MGIzMTMyNmQyMjMwOGY4MDUyYmZh",
    "_rid": "pR8YAPXxJQABAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/pR8YAA==/colls/pR8YAPXxJQA=/docs/pR8YAPXxJQABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"020094b9-0000-0000-0000-5980b3130000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1501606672   }
```

Is there a way to just query for a certain "searchTerm" (a field within my CosmosDB).  I cannot seem to grasp the Syntax to filter down my query.  I have tried a combination of things that would seem to make sense in SQL but none of it is working.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is a an entire set of web documentation specifically around the DocumentDB SQL query language. I suggest you start there. Unfortunately, your question, as written, is essentially a request for such tutorial / learning content (or it's a broad-stroke question on querying in general against DocumentDB). A quick web search of `documentdb sql` or `documentdb queries` should give you everything you need to get started.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am seeing basic examples of queries so maybe I should add that the $v is what is confusing me.  In most examples there is not the additional meta data that it seems like Azure added.  Do I include the $v in my query? For example c.$v.searchTerm?  This seems to also throw an error.  Thanks for any help!  If there is any documentation for this I would be more than happy to read up on it.  It just seems that every example I see does not discuss what the $v, $t actually means or why it is added. Sorry if this is a beginner mistake just trying to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @tydev53 Did you create your collection and insert documents through the Mongo API?

Comment: I created my collection using express and mongoose.  Maybe I need to define my schema better within my express app to get something that is easier to query. @JesseCarter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've stated in the comments you're using Mongoose which is an ORM for interacting with Mongo. If you're using the Mongo APIs to insert data you also need to use the Mongo APIs to query your data as they are built to support this document format with all the $ signs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to make sure I am understanding this correctly, because I am using Mongoose to insert my data into the DB that is what is adding the $ signs and all the additional attributes?  And this difference is what could be causing my problems with not being able to query inside the Azure "Query Explorer".  Basically you are saying I need to match up the API I am using to insert with how I query the data.

Comment: You're close. Mongoose is just a wrapper for communicating with Mongo. The Mongo API is what' adding the $ and attributes. Using the SQL APIs to try and retrieve Mongo data is going to be a headache, you should be using actual Mongo queries. I don't believe at this time there's a Mongo query explorer in the Azure portal, you'll have to execute your queries in another way

Comment: Ahh okay I think I got it!  I was able to query using the Mongo Query shell so it must just be an incompatibility to use the SQL "Query Explorer" APIs with how I am using Mongo.  Thank you for taking the time to explain the problem and what I was doing wrong.

Comment: np glad that it helped. One of Cosmos most interesting and powerful features is that you can use multiple APIs to interact with it but it can also add confusion if you're not familiar with how the different data formats and APIs interact with eachother

Answer (score 3):

With help from Jesse I was able to eventually get my query working using the SQL "Query Explorer" API.

As he explained since I am using an instance of MongoDb I should be using the Mongo Query API which can be accessed in Azure by going into "Data Explorer" -> select your collection -> "New Mongo Query". From there you can search using something similar to this...

```
{searchTerm: "test"}
```

Which returns all the searchTerms with the value test.

**How To Do It With SQL Query Explorer**

I wanted to do the same query with the SQL Query Explorer and after some trial and error the following syntax seems to work.

```
select *
from collection
where collection["$v"].searchTerm["$v"] = "test"
```

Not the prettiest solution but it worked.  Just wanted to mention this in case someone else was trying to query their mongodb with the SQL Query Explorer.

I was not familiar with this syntax and all documentation I could find did not bring up anything about this unique case.

Thanks.